# goinstall is not recognized as internal or external Command

Tags: go

I Am trying to install "goinstall github.com/alloy-d/goauth " but it is not working. giving the following error.

```
goinstall github.com/alloy-d/goauth

'goinstall' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And I tried with the git clone also but it is not creating exact structure.

```
git clone git://github.com/alloy-d/goauth
```

am installing it in the "$GOPATH"

Comment: As @iliacholy said ... `go` is the tool .. `install` is the command.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you should ask a separate question. Asking sub-questions is a bad idea: we won't see it, it doesn't fit the q&a style of SO, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, `goinstall` used to exist (now "[`go get`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)").

As explained in "[Configuration versus convention](https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html#tmp_1)":

> Over the last few years we consistently reminded people about the `goinstall` command (now replaced by go get) and its conventions:
>
> - first, that the import path is derived in a known way from the URL of the source code;
> - second, that the place to store the sources in the local file system is derived in a known way from the import path;
> - third, that each directory in a source tree corresponds to a single package;
> - and fourth, that the package is built using only information in the source code. Today, the vast majority of packages follow these conventions.

So you will find old tutorial using "`goinstall`".

In your case though, `go get` and then `go install` would work better.
Or `go install -v github.com/alloy-d/goauth` to see the details (the names of packages as they are compiled).

Comment: Interesting. Being fairly new to go.. when was it removed?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead January 2012, https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-dev/aj1FIy8x2VY (http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=7b819318c606, https://codereview.appspot.com/5572083), so around Go1.0

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: [Go 1 Release Notes: The go command](http://golang.org/doc/go1#cmd_go)

Comment: Heh... wow. I have always seen `go get` in all of my research.. thanks for the reference (both of you).